# Unknown data type: "DEFAULT"; SQL statement: while using hibernate.ddl-auto:true

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate

I am using H2 inMemory database for my springboot application. Where I have enabled `hibernate.ddl-auto`. Below is the `application.yml` content:

```
        spring:
          profiles: mock
          jpa:
            database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
            generate-ddl: true
            hibernate:
              ddl-auto: create
          datasource:
              jdbcUrl: jdbc:h2:mem:master
              driver-class-name: org.h2.Driver
              username:
              password:
              maximumPoolSize: 10
              minimumIdle: 5
              idleTimeout: 6000
              maxLifetime: 12000
              leakDetectionThreshold: 18000
              poolName: "primary"
```

and my entity class has an enumerated attribute as:

```java
@Column(name = "SOURCE", columnDefinition = "default 'MOBILE_APP'")
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private DocSource source;
```

spring throwing Unknown data type: `DEFAULT` exception while it's creating a schema for the above entity as its taking dataType as "Default" from `columnDefinition = "default 'MOBILE_APP'"`

```
        Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLNonTransientException: Unknown data type: "DEFAULT"; SQL statement:
        create table DMS_CUSTOMER_DOCUMENT_REF (ID bigint generated by default as identity, APPLICATION_ID varchar(255), CREATED_DATE timestamp, CUSTOMER_DOC_TYPE_ID bigint, DMS_DOC_ID varchar(255), DOC_VIEW default 'FRONT', IS_DELETED boolean, SOURCE default 'MOBILE_APP', primary key (ID)) [50004-200]
            at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:505)
            at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:429)
            at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:205)
            at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:181)
            at org.h2.command.Parser.parseColumnWithType(Parser.java:5971)
            at org.h2.command.Parser.parseColumnForTable(Parser.java:5697)
            at org.h2.command.Parser.parseTableColumnDefinition(Parser.java:8442)
            at org.h2.command.Parser.parseCreateTable(Parser.java:8379)
            at org.h2.command.Parser.parseCreate(Parser.java:6276)
            at org.h2.command.Parser.parsePrepared(Parser.java:903)
            at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:843)
            at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:815)
            at org.h2.command.Parser.prepareCommand(Parser.java:738)
            at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareLocal(Session.java:657)
            at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareCommand(Session.java:595)
            at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareCommand(JdbcConnection.java:1235)
            at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.executeUpdateInternal(JdbcStatement.java:164)
            at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.executeUpdate(JdbcStatement.java:126)
            at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.executeUpdate(ProxyStatement.java:120)
            at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyStatement.executeUpdate(HikariProxyStatement.java)
```

Is there a way where H2 will convert these types of column definitions in a correct way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to correct your field definition in this way:

```
@Column(name = "SOURCE", columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(20) default 'MOBILE_APP'")
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private DocSource source;
```

`columnDefinition` will override the sql DDL generated by hibernate for this particular column, but please note that it is non portable and depends on database you use.

So, as an alternative you can use [@ColumnDefault](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/ColumnDefault.html) annotation:

```java
@Entity
@DynamicInsert
public class YourEntity
{
   // ...
   @Column(name = "SOURCE")
   @ColumnDefault("'MOBILE_APP'")
   @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
   private DocSource source;

}
```

See also [this](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#schema-generation-column-default-value) section of hibernate documentation.

Comment: @maker If it solved your problem please [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) the answer.

Comment: Done. (was not aware of accepting a ans, thanks to highlight)